Do all these sentences mean the same thing?

My grammar is better than most people here.

My grammar is better than that of most people here.

My grammar is better than most people's here.


Are all these sentences grammatically correct and mean the same thing? If you had to use a sentence to mean what the second sentence does, what sentence would you use? In my mind, the second sentence is the best one to use here since the third one seems odd and the first one compares grammar with people.

The first means you are comparing grammar and people. Please show us you have looked up comparisons.

You could also say "I'm better at grammar than most people here".

#1 is grammatical, but doesn't mean quite the same thing the others do†. That said, it's a common error and in casual speech it's acceptable; native English speakers would understand from context what was meant.
If you're being formal (writing a report or taking a test, for example), #2 is certainly the best option, and #3 is an acceptable way to say the same thing.
† The distinction here is easier to see if you consider the difference between these two statements:

"My father's feet are bigger than most people's." (My father has unusually large feet.)
"My father's feet are bigger than most people." (My father is some sort of giant!)


No 1. is not at all grammatical and you would mislead a learner to suggest that it can be used informally, even if the intended meaning should be understood.  Lambie is correct. In an English test,  No. 1 would be marked wrong.

#1 is indeed grammatical, it just doesn't mean the same thing as the others. (We can argue about whether it's syntactically meaningful, but that's a whole different question. Colorless green ideas sleep furiously, after all.) I'll edit to be more clear about that, though.
